# How to tell if the value stored in a variable is even or odd?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm32, irvine32

Let's say I have a variable called numElements under the .data section and it currently stores the number 17. What kind of instruction can I use to determine if the value within numElements is even or odd? Is there an Irvine function for this, or is there another way to do it?

Comment: You know that in binary that just means you have to look at the least significant bit, right? You can do that using bitwise `and` or `test`.

Comment: @Jester I looked up the test instruction after reading your comment. If I understand correctly, I can test numElements to see if it's even or odd by using the statement "test numElements, 00000001b", but how do you "access" the result after the completion of the test?

Comment: `jz/jnz` or if you need actual number 1/0 then use `and`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.